# Why does Eclipse not show "Run" or "Run configuration"?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

Dears,

I just upgraded (and configured) my IDE to the Eclipse Mars edition for Java EE Developers with Tomcat8 as a Server. This configuration works for new Java EE projects (I tried a JSP "Hello World" project).

However, my old projects (the workspace of which I imported into the new Eclipse instance), which are exclusively Java SE projects all with a main method and formerly working, do not show a "Run" or "Run Configuration" option, no matter whether I switch to the Java EE or the Java perspective. What am I missing?

(As far as I understand the issue, I either misconfigured Eclipse or the Eclipse edition for "Java EE Develpers" does not support Standard Java projects. The latter option I deem unlikely; as far as I remember my previous Eclipse version was for EE Developers, too, although I never used its EE features.)

Thanks for your help!

Update: I just re-downloaded Eclipse for Java EE Developers from https://eclipse.org/downloads/ and re-installed it (on an Ubuntu 15.10 system) with the following commands:

```
rm -R /opt/eclipse-java-ee/eclipse/
mv Downloads/eclipse/ /opt/eclipse-java-ee/
```

And on the first run I pointed Eclipse to the same workspace as before.

Same problem as before: Neither "Run" nor "Run configuration" appear as an option in the "Run" menu or in the respective context menus.

Then I tried the following: Via "Quick Access" I find "Menus - Run Configurations ..." which I am able to access. The following "Create, manage, and run configurations" window lets me pick the current project under "Java Applications" and ... run it. This is a workaround, but not a solution. I still would like to be able to use the regular menu (and context menus).

Update 2: "Run", typed in the "Quick Access" box, works, too. So does Alt +  Shift + X, j. However, "Run as ..." in "Quick Access" doesn't do anything obvious.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but you can right-click on a project (in navigator, project explorer, ...) and select *Configure* - *Convert to ... project*

Comment: Yes, I saw this, but it gives me Faceted Form, JPA Project, JavaScript Project, Plug-In Project or Maven Project. Nothing which would help me, right?

Answer (score 4):

Look in 'Window > Perspective > Customize Perspective' in the 'Menu Visibility' tab and check that the 'Run' entries you want are turned on.
[image]

Comment: All entries are set. So unfortunately, this wasn't the problem either.

Comment: @kalabalik - do you remember how you solved this problem ?

Comment: I believe I reinstalled ... unfortunately.